# Parse the JSON array object from the Service in the Component

Tags: json, angular, object, typescript

This is the response I am passing from the Service to the Component where i should display each value to the UI. I need to parse each value and store to a variable.

```
[{"profileId":"000234","profileName":"kofi prfl","regionName":"NA  ","fileType":"GRRCN","fileVersion":"1.01","fileFreq":"D01","fileFormat":"FIX","emptyFile":"N","cardMask":"Y","uprInd":"N","dataLevel":"01"}]

this.profileDetailsService.getProfileDetails(this.idDisplay)
      .subscribe(profileResponse => {
          // Should parse the profileResponse here....
          this.searchResult = profileResponse;
          this.spinnerService.hide();
        },
      error => {
          this.spinnerService.hide();
          this.showError();
        }
      );
```

How to separate profileId, profileName, regionName etc., values?

Comment: Any chance you can post more code? Can I see your service, template and component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of in your code:

```
...
this.searchResult = profileResponse;
...
```

you can use:

```
searchResult: any[];

...
this.searchResult = profileResponse.json() || {}
...
```

then you can access each property via searchResult item:

```
this.searchResult[0].profileId, etc
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Was struggling for almost 8 hours with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on comment code:**

The reason you're not able to access the properties of `searchResult` is that the service is returning a response rather than a Javascript object with properties.

From the HTTP Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#!%23sts=Parse%20to%20JSON):

> The response data are in JSON string form. The app must parse that
>   string into JavaScript objects by calling response.json().

I suggest parsing the response in the service to keep things related to the http request there and prevent code duplication.

Change:

```
return this.http.post(this._url, body, options).map((response: Response) => {
    return response;
}).catch((error) => {
    return Observable.throw(error);
});
```

To this (if indeed you only want the first profile in the array):

```
 return this.http.post(this._url, body, options).map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json()[0];
    }).catch((error) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
```

The new code parses the JSON object and extracts the first object from the array with `.json()[0]`. Then rename `profileResponse` to `profileDetails` and access `this.searchResult`'s properties using dot notation:

e.g. From another function in the component:
`console.log(this.searchResult.profileName)`

e.g. From your template:
`{{searchResult.profileName}}`

Comment: profileResponse.profileId doesn't display the value in the field. It just shows undefined in the console.

Comment: Are you sure you're returning the actual object and not a json string from your service? Does your service call response.json()?

Comment: return this.http.post(this._url, body, options)
      .map((response:Response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });

this.profileDetailsService.getProfileDetails(this.idDisplay)
.subscribe(profileResponse => {
  this.value1 = profileResponse.profileId;
  this.value2 = profileResponse.profileName;
    this.searchResult = profileResponse;
    console.log("stringify values is "+ JSON.stringify(this.searchResult));
    this.spinnerService.hide();
  }
);

Comment: this is how i am passing the response from service to component.